# A gap between a Canvas object and its parent Toplevel object right side in a Tkinter GUI program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I'm developing a GUI program with Tkinter. It will work on 7" touch screen, full screen.
First, I made the main title.

```
import Tkinter as tk

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480

class Application(tk.Toplevel):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.overrideredirect(True)
    self.wm_geometry("800x480")
    self.cnvs = None
    self.showTitle()

  def showTitle(self):
    self.config(bg = 'white', borderwidth = 0)
    self.cnvs = TitleCanvas(self)
    self.cnvs.grid(sticky = tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S)

class TitleCanvas(tk.Canvas):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, width = SCREEN_WIDTH, height = SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    self.widgets = {}
    self.init_ui()

  def init_ui(self):
    # BG Color: White
    self.config(bg = 'white', borderwidth = 0)

    # Blank Area
    # Row: 0
    self.lblBlank = tk.Label(self, background = 'white', borderwidth = 0, text = '')
    self.lblBlank.grid(pady = 20, row = 0)

    # Title Image
    # Row: 1
    self.photoLogo = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'samplelogo.gif')
    self.lblLogo = tk.Label(self, image = self.photoLogo)
    self.lblLogo.grid(padx = 100, pady = 40, row = 10, sticky = tk.E + tk.W)

    # Text1
    # Row: 2
    self.lblLoad = tk.Label(self, background = 'white',
                      font = ("Helvetica", -30), text = "Loading...")
    self.lblLoad.grid(pady = 60, row = 2, sticky = tk.E + tk.W)

    # Text2
    # Row: 3
    self.lblVer = tk.Label(self, background = 'white',
                     font = ("Helvetica", -30), text = "Company and Version")
    self.lblVer.grid(pady = 30, row = 3, sticky = tk.E + tk.W)

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

[image]

The Canvas object should fill the whole screen. But it doesn't reach to the edge of the right side.
To remove the gap, what should I do?

Comment: (you should add a different background in your example to make the gap visible)

Comment: Does that mean the background options in each widgets caused the gap? I removed all background options but Toplevel, but the gap wasn't removed. I guess it's because of another cause.

Comment: Why did I use grid() in canvas? The problem has been solved. I use create_image() and create_text() methods instead grid(). Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with create_image() and create_text(). these methods are able to set the position of widgets.

TitleCanvas.init_ui() method can be revised like this;

```
def init_ui(self):
  #BG Color: White
  self.config(bg = 'white', borderwidth = 0)

  # Background 
  self.create_rectangle((0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), fill = 'white')

  # Title Image
  #Center Point: (400, 160)
  self.photoLogo = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'samplelogo.gif')
  self.create_image(400, 160, anchor = tk.CENTER, image = self.photoLogo)

  # Text1
  self.create_text((400, 315), text = 'Loading...')

  # Text2
  self.create_text((400, 435), text = 'Company and Version')
```